# Matlab - Plotting rectangle without using rectangle function

Tags: matlab, plot, draw

How do i plot a rectangle using the plot function. I cant use rectangle(). I currently am using

```
theta2 = linspace(0,2*pi,5);
plot(radius.*cos(theta2)+xCentre,radius.*sin(theta2)+yCentre,'k');
```

but this plots a diamond rather than a rectangle.

Comment: 90 degree angles, looks like a rectangle to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for drawing rectangle without using `rectangle()`

```
length=5;
width=2;
xCentre=0;
yCentre=0;

u=[-1 1 1 -1];
x=[u u(1)].*(length/2);
u=circshift(u,[0 -1]);
y=[u u(1)].*(width/2);
plot(x,y,'k');
xlim([x(1)-2,x(2)+2]);
ylim([y(3)-2,y(2)+2])
```

Answer (score 1):

To plot ROI (rectangle with sides parallel to the axes)

```
line([xL, xR, xR, xL, xL], [yT, yT, yB, yB, yT], 'Color','red','LineWidth',3)
```

where xL, xR - left/right sides,
yT, yB - top/bottom sides

To plot any quadrangle

```
line([x1, x2, x3, x4, x1], [y1, y2, y3, y4, y1], 'Color','red','LineWidth',3)
```